Refresh Infinite Loop happening when trying to request in access token in a React Web App
I'm only a couple months in of learning front end development. I wrote a module to:
Make a GET fetch quest for an access token with the Spotify API
Parse the resulting authorization url for the access token and expiration time and set it to localstorage in the browser.
I know Implicit Grant Flow isn't recommended for security reasons, but this is just a little portfolio project not intended for mass use.
I'm running into an issue where instead of loading Spotify's authorization page right off the bat, it goes straight to the redirect_uri and then the url blinks rapidly which I think means there is some sort of refresh loop that keeps happening. I've searched over the Spotify documentation, chat GPT etc...and I can't figure it out.
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const generateRandomString = (length) => {
  const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
  let result = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length));
  }
  return result;
};

const SpotifyAccessToken = ({ stateLength }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const clientId = '';
    const redirectUri = 'http://localhost:5173/';
    const scope = 'playlist-modify-private playlist-modify-public user-read-private';
    const responseType = 'token';
    const state = generateRandomString(stateLength)

    const queryParams = new URLSearchParams({
      client_id: clientId,
      redirect_uri: redirectUri,
      scope: scope,
      response_type: responseType,
      state: state,
    });

    const authorizeUrl = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?${queryParams}`;

    // Redirect the user to the authorize URL
    window.location.href = authorizeUrl;
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const error = queryParams.get('error');

    if (error) {
      console.error('Authorization error:', error);
      
      return;
    }

    const accessToken = queryParams.get('access_token');
    const expiresIn = parseInt(queryParams.get('expires_in'));
    const expirationTime = new Date().getTime() + expiresIn * 1000;

    localStorage.setItem('spotifyAccessToken', accessToken);
    localStorage.setItem('spotifyTokenExpirationTime', expirationTime);

    if (expirationTime < Date.now()) {
      // Token has expired, redirect to the initial authorization URL
      const clientId = 'd90891e3a05449b5992d7c531d9a8cc1';
      const redirectUri = 'http://localhost:5173/';
      const scope = 'playlist-modify-private playlist-modify-public user-read-private';
      const responseType = 'token';
      const state = generateRandomString(stateLength)

      const queryParams = new URLSearchParams({
        client_id: clientId,
        redirect_uri: redirectUri,
        scope: scope,
        response_type: responseType,
        state: state,
      });

      const authorizeUrl = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?${queryParams}`;

      window.location.href = authorizeUrl;
    } else {
      // Clear parameters from the URL to avoid potential issues
      window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, window.location.pathname);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Redirecting to Spotify for access...</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SpotifyAccessToken;


The infinite loop of refresh in your first code is likely due to the fact that you're redirecting the user to the Spotify authorization URL inside the first useEffect hook, which runs on component mount ([] dependency array). Then, after the user is redirected back to your application from Spotify, the second useEffect hook executes, but it doesn't have any dependencies specified ([] dependency array).
Therefore, it runs on every render, including after the access token is received, leading to a continuous loop of redirection and re-rendering.
[Render] --> [Redirect to Spotify] --> [Redirect back to application] --> [Render] --> ...

So I changed the your code and displayed the access token in a browser by Implicit Grant flow.
There's no need for a CLIENT_SECRET because:
The CLIENT_SECRET is typically used in conjunction with the CLIENT_ID for server-side authentication flows, such as the Authorization Code Grant flow, where the client can securely store and use the CLIENT_SECRET to authenticate itself with the authorization server.
However, in the Implicit Grant flow, the access token is sent directly to the client application via the browser, so there's no need for the client to authenticate itself with a CLIENT_SECRET.
App.js
import React from 'react';
import SpotifyAccessToken from './SpotifyAccessToken';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const clientId = '{Your Spotify client ID}';
  const redirectUri = 'http://localhost:3000/callback'; // Your redirect with port URI and "start": port in package.json
  const scope = 'user-read-private user-read-email'; // Your desired scope

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <SpotifyAccessToken clientId={clientId} redirectUri={redirectUri} scope={scope} />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

SpotifyAccessToken.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const SpotifyAccessToken = ({ clientId, redirectUri, scope }) => {
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.hash.substring(1));
    const token = params.get('access_token');
    if (token) {
      setAccessToken(token);
    }
  }, []);

  const handleLogin = () => {
    // Redirect to Spotify authorization endpoint
    window.location.href = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?${
      new URLSearchParams({
        response_type: 'token',
        client_id: clientId,
        redirect_uri: redirectUri,
        scope: scope,
      }).toString()
    }`;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {!accessToken ? (
        <button onClick={handleLogin}>Login with Spotify</button>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <p>Successfully logged in!</p>
          <p>Access Token: {accessToken}</p>
          {/* Now you can use the accessToken to make requests to the Spotify API */}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SpotifyAccessToken;

package.json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=3000 react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}

Note: if your callback port number is different, you need to change
 "start": "PORT={your port number} react-scripts start",

Run it
npm start

Result

Press Login with Spotify

